# SQLITE unir 2 sentencia SELECT y agrupar resultados

Tags: sqlite3

Tengo 2 tablas sqlite en mi bd. Una llamada master y la otra detail, master contiene nombre de proyectos web y detail las tareas pendientes a realizar. Aqui las tablas

```
master
------------------
nombreproyecto
version
-----------------
```

y la tabla detail

```
detal
-------------------
nombreproyectodetail
tarealizar
```

Todos los campos son del tipo TEXT
He hecho la siguiente sentencia para seleccionar aquel proyecto que tenga tareas a realizar de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT DISTINCT master.nombreproyecto FROM master
INNER JOIN detail ON detail.nombreproyectodetail = master.nombreproyecto
ORDER BY master.nombreproyecto ASC
```

Y he hecho la siguiente sentencia para sumar las tareas de cada proyecto

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTALES
 FROM detail
 INNER JOIN master ON master.nombreproyecto = detail.nombreproyectodetail
 GROUP BY detail.nombreproyectodetail
```

mi consulta cómo puedo si en vez de tener 2 sentencias por separado tener una sentencia sola que me devuelva
por ejemplo:

```
Nombre     Cantidad
---------------------
proyecto1  2 tareas
proyecto5  6 tareas
```

Desde ya muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select detail.nombreproyecto, count(detail.nombreproyecto) as total
From detail inner join máster
on máster.nombreproyecto = detail.nombreproyectodetail 
Group by detail.nombreproyectodetail;
```

Lo que se hace aquí es que se enlazan las dos tablas en el from se agrupa como haces en tu ejemplo y en el select se proyecta el total y el nombre del proyecto según tu ejemplo

Comment: Con algunas correciones funcionó.Genio total. Gracias!